# How to add \r\n to use in a variable in sed?

Tags: bash, sed

i finally find out the cause of problem
The code works when `dateRecent='2011 年\r\n 7 月 25 日'`

```
#!/bin/bash
cp /var/www/html/INFOSEC/textonly/sc_chi/anti/recent.html /var/www/html/INFOSEC/textonly/sc_chi/anti/recent.test.html


dateRecent='2011 年\r\n 7 月 25 日'
title=test
web=http:a.com

#Add Phishing attack in recent.html
sed -i '0,/<li>/ { s/<li>/<li><a href="'"$web"'" target="_blank">'"$dateRecent"' - '"$title"'<\/a><\/li>\r\n                              <li>/ }' /var/www/html/INFOSEC/textonly/sc_chi/anti/recent.test.html
```

However, dateRecent is a variable and user input , i can't manually add a '  ' quote .

```
#!/bin/bash
cp /var/www/html/INFOSEC/textonly/sc_chi/anti/recent.html /var/www/html/INFOSEC/textonly/sc_chi/anti/recent.test.html

echo "enter date"
read -e date <== it should be something like 2011 年 7 月 25 日
dateRecent=$(sed 's/ 年/ 年\r\n/g' <<< $date)
title=test
web=http:a.com

#Add Phishing attack in recent.html
sed -i '0,/<li>/ { s/<li>/<li><a href="'"$web"'" target="_blank">'"$dateRecent"' - '"$title"'<\/a><\/li>\r\n                              <li>/ }' /var/www/html/INFOSEC/textonly/sc_chi/anti/recent.test.html
```

So, i tried `dateRecent='$dateRecent'` and `'"'$dateRecent'"'`
but it just don't work, thanks

I also, found that if echo the dateRecent

```
#!/bin/bash
cp /var/www/html/INFOSEC/textonly/sc_chi/anti/recent.html /var/www/html/INFOSEC/textonly/sc_chi/anti/recent.test.html

echo "enter date"
read -e date
dateRecent=$(sed 's/ 年/ 年\r\n/g' <<< $date)
echo $dateRecent
dateRecent='$dateRecent'
echo $dateRecent
title=test
web=http:a.com

#Add Phishing attack in recent.html
sed -i '0,/<li>/ { s/<li>/<li><a href="'"$web"'" target="_blank">'"$dateRecent"' - '"$title"'<\/a><\/li>\r\n                              <li>/ }' /var/www/html/INFOSEC/textonly/sc_chi/anti/recent.test.html
```

The input is 2011 年 7 月 25 日 but output would be:

```
 7 月 25 日
$dateRecent
```

Comment: ./test.sh: line 5: 年rn: command not found

Comment: How do you call the script from the command line? can you provide the full command line please?

Comment: just save as test.sh and ./test.sh to call

Comment: You say: "dateRecent is a variable and user input"; how do you pass that on the command line? do you use quote there? `test.sh "2011 年\r\n 7 月 25 日"`?

Comment: alright edited pls have a look thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add \r\n in a varaible in sed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895304/how-to-add-r-n-in-a-varaible-in-sed)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with this?

```
...
dateRecent=$(sed 's/ 年/ 年\r\n/g' <<< $date)
dateRecent="\"$dateRecent\""
...
```

Comment: if i use it as user input
sed: -e expression #1, char 69: unterminated `s' command